# Running a command in a new Mac OS X Terminal window

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I've been trying to figure out how to run a bash command in a new Max OS X Terminal.app window. As, an example, here's how I would run my command in a new bash process:

```
bash -c "my command here"
```

But this reuses the existing terminal window instead of creating a new one. I want something like:

```
Terminal.app -c "my command here"
```

But of course this doesn't work. I am aware of the "open -a Terminal.app" command, but I don't see how to forward arguments to the terminal, or even if I did what arguments to use.

Comment: You could always open preferences, goto the "Profiles" tab, go into the "Shell" page and set the startup command there. It only runs when the application is opened, but it works better than the hacky alternatives!

Comment: Also see the same question at superuser https://superuser.com/q/174576/122841

Comment: Many beginners _think_ they want this, until they learn how to run and manipulate background processes. Having a command run in the background with output to a file lets you examine the output file from any terminal, and elegantly scales to many more processes than you can usefully keep track of in simultaneously open interactive but read-only terminal windows.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

one way I can think to do it off the top of my head is to create a .command file and run it like so:

```
echo echo hello > sayhi.command; chmod +x sayhi.command; open sayhi.command
```

or use applescript:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "echo hello"'
```

although you'll either have to escape a lot of double quotes or not be able to use single quotes

Comment: I've decided on the first method. It's pretty hack-ish, but it works and I don't have to worry about escaping quotes in my command or anything. Thanks.

Comment: If the command needs to run parametrized, perhaps you'll want to swap the single and double quotes; though you need to understand the difference in order to be able to do this correctly. `osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"echo '$variable'\"'`

Comment: anyone know how to close the stupid left over terminal window?

Comment: Add `; exit` at the end of the shell script commands, like `do script "echo hello; exit"`. You still need to close the window separately.

Answer (score 68):

Partial solution:

Put the things you want done in a shell-script, like so

```
#!/bin/bash
ls
echo "yey!"
```

And don't forget to '`chmod +x file`' to make it executable. Then you can

```
open -a Terminal.app scriptfile
```

and it will run in a new window. Add '`bash`' at the end of the script to keep the new session from exiting. (Although you might have to figure out how to load the users rc-files and stuff..)

Comment: The context of the newly opened window seems to be the user's root folder `/Users/{username}`. Is there any way to keep the context folder the same as the parent terminal window that opened it?

Comment: > Although you might have to figure out how to load the users rc-files and stuff..
use bash -l for this

Answer (score 35):

I've been trying to do this for a while.  Here is a script that changes to the same working directory, runs the command, and closes the terminal window.

```
#!/bin/sh 
osascript <<END 
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "cd \"`pwd`\";$1;exit"
end tell
END
```

Comment: Dislike accepted script, your one solve current directory problem. Thanks!

Comment: Great solution; it outputs something like `tab 1 of window id 7433` to stdout in the *launching* shell, though. To suppress that, place `>/dev/null` *before* `<<END`.

Comment: This doesn't inherently close the terminal window. It just exits the command interpreter. Terminal.app has to be configured to close the window automatically, or on clean exit of command interpreter.

Answer (score 8):

In case anyone cares, here's an equivalent for iTerm:

```
#!/bin/sh
osascript <<END
tell application "iTerm"
 tell the first terminal
  launch session "Default Session"
  tell the last session
   write text "cd \"`pwd`\";$1;exit"
  end tell
 end tell
end tell
END
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's yet another take on it (also using AppleScript):

```
function newincmd() { 
   declare args 
   # escape single & double quotes 
   args="${@//\'/\'}" 
   args="${args//\"/\\\"}" 
   printf "%s" "${args}" | /usr/bin/pbcopy 
   #printf "%q" "${args}" | /usr/bin/pbcopy 
   /usr/bin/open -a Terminal 
   /usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script with command "/usr/bin/clear; eval \"$(/usr/bin/pbpaste)\""' 
   return 0 
} 

newincmd ls 

newincmd echo "hello \" world" 
newincmd echo $'hello \' world'
```

see: codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/1516

Comment: This was the only one that worked for me. My need was that I needed to run a command that would create an ssh tunnel to a machine, and then after that I wanted to open a vncloc to screen share it. I could do it perfectly in a new bash function in 3 steps: tunnel command in new window, sleep 3 seconds, then open the vncloc in original window. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my awesome script, it creates a new terminal window if needed and switches to the directory Finder is in if Finder is frontmost. It has all the machinery you need to run commands.

```
on run
    -- Figure out if we want to do the cd (doIt)
    -- Figure out what the path is and quote it (myPath)
    try
        tell application "Finder" to set doIt to frontmost
        set myPath to finder_path()
        if myPath is equal to "" then
            set doIt to false
        else
            set myPath to quote_for_bash(myPath)
        end if
    on error
        set doIt to false
    end try

    -- Figure out if we need to open a window
    -- If Terminal was not running, one will be opened automatically
    tell application "System Events" to set isRunning to (exists process "Terminal")

    tell application "Terminal"
        -- Open a new window
        if isRunning then do script ""
        activate
        -- cd to the path
        if doIt then
            -- We need to delay, terminal ignores the second do script otherwise
            delay 0.3
            do script " cd " & myPath in front window
        end if
    end tell
end run

on finder_path()
    try
        tell application "Finder" to set the source_folder to (folder of the front window) as alias
        set thePath to (POSIX path of the source_folder as string)
    on error -- no open folder windows
        set thePath to ""
    end try

    return thePath
end finder_path

-- This simply quotes all occurrences of ' and puts the whole thing between 's
on quote_for_bash(theString)
    set oldDelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "'"
    set the parsedList to every text item of theString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "'\\''"
    set theString to the parsedList as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelims
    return "'" & theString & "'"
end quote_for_bash
```

Answer (score 3):

I made a function version of Oscar's answer, this one also copies the environment and changes to the appropriate directory

```
function new_window {
    TMP_FILE=$(mktemp "/tmp/command.XXXXXX")
    echo "#!/usr/bin/env bash" > $TMP_FILE

    # Copy over environment (including functions), but filter out readonly stuff
    set | grep -v "\(BASH_VERSINFO\|EUID\|PPID\|SHELLOPTS\|UID\)" >> $TMP_FILE

    # Copy over exported envrionment
    export -p >> $TMP_FILE

    # Change to directory
    echo "cd $(pwd)" >> $TMP_FILE

    # Copy over target command line
    echo "$@" >> $TMP_FILE

    chmod +x "$TMP_FILE"
    open -b com.apple.terminal "$TMP_FILE"

    sleep .1 # Wait for terminal to start
    rm "$TMP_FILE"
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
new_window my command here
```

or

```
new_window ssh example.com
```

Comment: The line `TMP_FILE="tmp.command"` could be a problem if you start more than one process simultaneously. I would suggest to replace it by `TMP_FILE=$(mktemp "/tmp/command.XXXXXX")`

Answer (score 2):

A colleague asked me how to open A LOT of ssh sessions at once.  I used cobbal's answer to write this script:

```
tmpdir=$( mktemp -d )
trap '$DEBUG rm -rf $tmpdir ' EXIT
index=1

{
cat <<COMMANDS
ssh user1@host1
ssh user2@host2
COMMANDS
} | while read command
do 
  COMMAND_FILE=$tmpdir/$index.command
  index=$(( index + 1 ))
  echo $command > $COMMAND_FILE
  chmod +x  $COMMAND_FILE
  open $COMMAND_FILE
done
sleep 60
```

By updating the list of commands ( they don't have to be ssh invocations ), you will get an additional open window for every command executed.   The `sleep 60` at the end is there to keep the `.command` files around while they are being executed.  Otherwise, the shell completes too quickly, executing the trap to delete the temp directory ( created by mktemp ) before the launched sessions have an opportunity to read the files.

Answer (score 2):

#### Another option that needs to be here is "`ttab`"

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ttab

###### Install

```
npm install ttab -g
```

###### Usage : Open another tab and run `ls`

```
ttab ls
```

###### Usage 2 : Open new tab, with Green BG, with title "hi", in directory ~/dev, and run `code .`

```
ttab -s Grass -t hi -d '~/dev' code .
```

Comment: great hint. It is a pity that needs Nodejs but on the plus side it is cross platform!

Answer (score 1):

I call this script trun. I suggest putting it in a directory in your executable path. Make sure it is executable like this:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/trun
```

Then you can run commands in a new window by just adding trun before them, like this:

```
trun tail -f /var/log/system.log
```

Here's the script. It does some fancy things like pass your arguments, change the title bar, clear the screen to remove shell startup clutter, remove its file when its done. By using a unique file for each new window it can be used to create many windows at the same time.

```
#!/bin/bash
# make this file executable with chmod +x trun
# create a unique file in /tmp
trun_cmd=`mktemp`
# make it cd back to where we are now
echo "cd `pwd`" >$trun_cmd
# make the title bar contain the command being run
echo 'echo -n -e "\033]0;'$*'\007"' >>$trun_cmd
# clear window
echo clear >>$trun_cmd
# the shell command to execute
echo $* >>$trun_cmd
# make the command remove itself
echo rm $trun_cmd >>$trun_cmd
# make the file executable
chmod +x $trun_cmd

# open it in Terminal to run it in a new Terminal window
open -b com.apple.terminal $trun_cmd
```

Comment: The incorrect usage of `$*` throughout will wreck any nontrivial quoting in the input. You want `"$@"` instead.

Comment: I was looking for `open -b com.apple.terminal`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could also invoke the **new command** feature of Terminal by pressing the `Shift + ⌘ + N` key combination. The command you put into the box will be run in a new Terminal window.

Comment: Of course useful to know, but I need to do it programatically. Having my program generate a .command file and then open it is a reasonable (if a bit hackish) solution.