# String concatenation for a bash script command

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write an alias in my `~/.bashrc` of this form:

```
alias a="foo; osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "bar"; baz"
```

(where `bar` launches in a new Terminal window, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989349/running-a-command-in-a-new-mac-os-x-terminal-window)) but this string doesn't look like it will parse. I tried string interpolation (`${str}`), but the problem seems to be unsolvable that way.

Comment: That's probably `~/.bashrc` (without the underscore).

Comment: Oops, thanks. Been working in Ruby too much. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

```
alias a="foo; osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"bar\"'; baz"
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, the string appears to work fine as written. As long as it's on one line, Bash doesn't terminate the double-quoted string the way you'd expect.

**Update**: As Ignacio points out, the string as written doesn't preserve the double quotes within it. To wit:

```
# Good:
a="foo; osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"bar\"'; baz"
echo $a
> foo; osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "bar"'; baz

# Not so good:
b="foo; osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "bar"'; baz"
echo $b
> foo; osascript -e 'tell application Terminal to do script bar'; baz
```

Comment: Nope. But it won't quote those pieces either.