# How can I get rid of this osascript output?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, osascript

The following question relates to an answer that was posted on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989349/running-a-command-in-a-new-mac-os-x-terminal-window):

I like the notion of creating my own function that opens a new terminal, so the script that Craig Walker linked to in that above-referenced question suited my needs. The script, written by Mark Liyanage, is found [here.](http://www.entropy.ch/blog/Mac+OS+X/?permalink=Terminal_tricks_8220_term_8221_and_8220_clone_8221.html)

That script is this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Open a new Mac OS X terminal window with the command given
# as argument.
#
# - If there are no arguments, the new terminal window will
#   be opened in the current directory, i.e. as if the command
#   would be "cd `pwd`".
# - If the first argument is a directory, the new terminal will
#   "cd" into that directory before executing the remaining
#   arguments as command.
# - If there are arguments and the first one is not a directory,
#   the new window will be opened in the current directory and
#   then the arguments will be executed as command.
# - The optional, leading "-x" flag will cause the new terminal
#   to be closed immediately after the executed command finishes.
#
# Written by Marc Liyanage <http://www.entropy.ch>
#
# Version 1.0
#

if [ "x-x" = x"$1" ]; then
    EXIT="; exit"; shift;
fi

if [[ -d "$1" ]]; then
    WD=`cd "$1"; pwd`; shift;
else
    WD="'`pwd`'";
fi

COMMAND="cd $WD; $@"
#echo "$COMMAND $EXIT"

osascript 2>/dev/null <<EOF
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script with command "$COMMAND $EXIT"
    end tell
EOF
```

I made one change to the script on the linked site; I commented out the line that outputs "$COMMAND $EXIT" to eliminate some verbosity. However, when I run the script I still get this output

```
tab 1 of window id 2835
```

just before it opens the new window and executes the command that I pass in. Any ideas why this would be happening? (I tried moving the redirect of stderr to /dev/null before the call to oascript, but that made no difference.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`tab 1 of window 2835` is the AppleScript representation of the object returned by the `do script` command: it is the `tab` instance created to execute the command. `osascript` returns the results of the script execution to standard output. Since there is no explicit `return` in the AppleScript script, the returned value of the whole script is the result of the last-executed statement, normally the `do script` command.  The two easiest fixes are to either redirect stdout of the osascript (and preferably *not* redirect stderr in case of errors):

```
osascript >/dev/null <<EOF
```

or insert an explicit `return` (with no value) into the AppleScript.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script with command "$COMMAND $EXIT"
end tell
return
```

Comment: Works like a charm. The original script had 
osascript 2>/dev/null <<EOF
which was redirecting stderr to /dev/null, which is why I moved it. I didn't think to try redirecting regular output to /dev/null... Thanks!