# AIR NativeProcess API

Tags: c++, air

I use nativeprocess api in AIR to launch a c++ console app. The console app runs correctly but does not appear, but I want it to be visible and user be able to interact with it. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of launching your executable directly, you'll need to launch your platform's terminal application (on Windows, that's `CMD.exe`, on OS-X it's `Terminal.app`, and on unix/linux it's `xterm`).

By default, the terminal application will run an interactive shell prompt, but you can use command-line arguments to tell it to execute any other program instead.  In this case, you'll want to tell it to execute your C++ console application.

On Windows, this might look something like this:

```
CMD.exe /K C:\path\to\your\app.exe
```

on OS-X, it's a little more complicated.  Here's a related S.O. post ( [Running a command in a new Mac OS X Terminal window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989349/running-a-command-in-a-new-mac-os-x-terminal-window))