# How do you invoke a terminal through a command and cd to a directory?

Tags: macos, command-line, cd

I'm trying to invoke a terminal from the command line and cd into a particular directory on my MAC machine. I understand that this can be done using this command on Linux.

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory="/path/to/new/directory"
```

Is there an equivalent in Mac without actually writing an AppleScript? 
I know this command opens a new terminal though.

```
open -a Terminal.app
```

All I need to figure out is a way to add an argument to cd into another directory from the new terminal.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
dkulkarni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a sensible way to pass Terminal a simple command-line request like this. I agree that's a bit daft, but there you go. The accepted way is via AppleScript. If you really can't stomach that, write out a shell command and `open` that instead.

Examples of both approaches can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989349/running-a-command-in-a-new-mac-os-x-terminal-window/989357#989357). Note that if you're writing a `.command` file there will be an implicit `exit` afterwards, so you need to stick an extra shell at the end, something like this:

```
echo cd /\;bash > /tmp/new.command;chmod +x /tmp/new.command; open /tmp/new.command
```

And the environment probably won't end up being set up how you want it. The AppleScript method is a bit less  hacky and should leave you with the correct environment:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "cd /"'
```

Works for me, anyway.