# How to run node-inspector automatically when server starts?

Tags: node.js

I'm using node-inspector for debugging my server code. every time I start my server I need to start node-inspector too.  How can I start node-inspector without opening another terminal and write the command `$ node-inspector`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about running the like of `gnome-terminal --execute node-inspector` or `pterm -e node-inspector` (the command depends on what terminal program you prefer) via `child_process.spawn` at the start of the server code?

Comment: yes but i'm not sure how one would invoke the terminal from the command line on that platform. but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577222/how-do-you-invoke-a-terminal-through-a-command-and-cd-to-a-directory references http://stackoverflow.com/questions/989349/running-a-command-in-a-new-mac-os-x-terminal-window/989357#989357 which says that it can be done via applescript using a command like `osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "node-inspector"'`.