# How to execute simultaneous PHP CLI scripts in Mac

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have 50 php files that I would like to run simultaneously from the command line. Right now, I am running them in multiple CLI windows using the code:

php Script1.php

I would like to be able to call one single script file that would execute all 50 php files simultaneously. I have been reading about how to make the command line not wait for the output, but I can't seem to make it work.

I am new to both MAC and Scripting - maybe I don't need a script? Is there another mac based solultion that can do this without me having to open 50 separate terminal windows?

Comment: Do they need to run _simultaneously_, or is it sufficient that the next one will start when the previous one ended?

Comment: Just put an `&` on the end of the line.

Comment: They do need to run simultaneously. The script I am running is based on each state. To process it in series takes about 12 hours, and I need to cut that down - 50 times less to be exact :) I was able to run them simultaneously by opening up multiple windows, but I am trying to simply that process.

Comment: Sorry, I could have been more clear - each US state

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just add ampersand '`&`' to separate each command:

```
php script1.php & php script2.php & php script3.php ...
```

This ampersand symbol will tell the shell to run command on background.

To check the output, you can redirect it to a file:

```
php script1.php > script1.log.txt & php script2.php > script2.log.txt
```

And you can just do a `tail` on it to read the log:

```
tail -f script1.log.txt
```

Comment: How would I then interact with the script after it is in the background? Know if it started or stopped correctly or abruptly? thanks for the help so far!

Comment: the easiest way is to redirect it's output to a file, and check it.

Answer (score 1):

If you script is nicely numbered from 1 to 50, you can try the following in a `.command` file:

```
i=1;
while [ $i -lt 51 ]
do
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
    do script "php Script$i.php"
end tell' &
i=$[$i+1]
done
```

This should open 50 separate terminal windows each running script{$i}.php

Comment: Andreas, thanks for this. It's very helpful if I wanted to open these windows simultaneously. I ran the script and each window opened, but it just said '  .php cannot be found.' What type of scripting language is this? Can you recommend a link to learn more?

Comment: This is actually mac .command file which you can run by double clicking it or running it from your Terminal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/989349/running-a-command-in-a-new-mac-os-x-terminal-window

Comment: Make sure when you run that you are in the directory where Script1-50 are

Comment: Nifty, could you please clarify your script? I copied and pasted, but it wont print the variable $i value in Script$i.php. It just repeats 'Script$i.php' over and over instead of printing out the script value. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a mac handy at the moment.. That script is supposed to open a new terminal for each Script$i.php, do you see that behavior?

Comment: ah, I got it, thank you. it was an issue with how it was quoted. Working great now!

Comment: @user658182 glad to hear that, mind telling me which quote was wrong? I would like to edit my answer :)

Comment: I changed 
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
    do script "php Script$i.php"
end tell' 

to 

osascript -e "tell app \"Terminal\"
do script \"php Script$i.php\"
end tell"

Answer (score 1):

You could also run them at the same time but not in the background.

```
php test1.php; php test2.php;
```

I don't know why you would want to "interact" with the script after its running.