# Java starting running command in new terminal (mac osx) - process builder not running osascript properly

Tags: java, macos, applescript, processbuilder, osascript

I'm trying to create a new process in a new window. I'm following this example for the command [Running a command in a new Mac OS X Terminal window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989349/running-a-command-in-a-new-mac-os-x-terminal-window) (using Java Process builder). I printed out the resulting command and it works if I type it in manually, but it doesn't start the new window when I run it.

Something as simple as `osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "java -jar test.jar"'` doesn't bring anything up

Sample code:

```
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("osascript", "-e",
            "'tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"java -jar test.jar\"'");
        Process p = pb.start();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It doesn't even bring up an error (as it should if it were starting the java process in a new terminal window)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And as usual although I spend hours looking into my problem I find the silly solution after I ask stack overflow... don't need the single quotes around `tell application...`. Process builder does that. Er, not sure if question needs to be closed. Quite localized, but certainly confusing IMO