# OSX script to open a new iTerm window and run a command based on a variable

Tags: macos, bash, shell, iterm, osascript

I am trying to use the iTerm example shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989349/running-a-command-in-a-new-mac-os-x-terminal-window) in answer to another query.

Basically I have a list of about 20 text files representing reports from different servers. I want to read each file name in the directory they live in and from that build a shell command that exists in a commands directory, then open a new iTerm window and then execute that shell script that I built.

I don't want to run them all in one window one after the other, I want them each to execute in their own window to speed up the processing.

Here is what I have, I can build the shell script name and store in foo quite happily and it seems I can open the new iTerm window OK too, but it is getting it to accept $foo as the command to be run I am having trouble with.

```
#!/bin/sh
FILES=/Volumes/reporter/uplod/lists/*
# eg each filename is of the type <path>/X07QXL29.txt
for f in $FILES
do
  foo="del"
  foo+=${f:32:1}
  foo+=${f:36:2}
  foo+=".sh"
  # foo is now for example del729.sh using the above comment as the filename
  # foo is the command I will want to run in its own new window
  osascript <<END
    tell application "iTerm"
        tell the first terminal
        tell myterm
            launch session "Default Session"
            tell the last session
                write text "$foo"
                write text "\n"
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
  END
done
```

The error I am getting is:deltrash.sh: line 22: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Can anyone please give me a pointer?

Comment: Are you only doing each process in a new window in order to make it run faster? If so, you could run all processes in a single window in parallel by adding an ampersand to the end of each command. Or you could run them all in parallel with `GNU Parallel` using the `-k` switch to keep the output separated and in order.

Comment: Yes I'd like to be able to see the output of he command in each window, so having them all display in a single window would be problematic for me.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at `iTerm` applescript [examples](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/wikis/Applescript), something like that should work. Basically you have to set `myterm` variable to new terminal instance. Also be sure to put `END` marker at the beginning of line. It is not detected in your script, hence `unexpected end of file` error.

```
#!/bin/sh
FILES=/Volumes/reporter/uplod/lists/*
# eg each filename is of the type <path>/X07QXL29.txt
for f in $FILES
do
  foo="del"
  foo+=${f:32:1}
  foo+=${f:36:2}
  foo+=".sh"
  # foo is now for example del729.sh using the above comment as the filename
  # foo is the command I will want to run in its own new window
  osascript <<END
    tell application "iTerm"
        set myterm to (make new terminal)
        tell myterm
            launch session "Default Session"
            tell the last session
                write text "$foo"
                write text "\n"
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
END
done
```