# Launch Python script in new terminal

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, subprocess, terminal.app

I want to launch a python script in a new macOS terminal window from another script. I'm currently using this code:

```
subprocess.call(['open', '-a', 'Terminal.app', '/usr/bin/python'])
```

which launches a python prompt in a new terminal window.
But when I try to run a python script with this code:

```
subprocess.call(['open', '-a', 'Terminal.app', '/usr/bin/python', 'test.py'])
```

it completely ignores the `'test.py'` on the end and starts a python prompt, just like it does without the test.py on the end.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Likely dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/989349/running-a-command-in-a-new-mac-os-x-terminal-window [see osascript solution]

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `open -a terminal.app`, just use the python executable

```
subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/python', 'test.py'])
```

Comment: Just to clarify, I need it in a terminal window so that the user of my script can see the output and interact with the script. Thanks for answering though!

Answer (score 0):

This Python code will open a new terminal window, and then have python3 run test.py:

```
import os
os.system("""osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "python3 test.py"'""")
```

I'm unable to come up with a way to get this into a `subprocess.call()` call.