# Python & macOS: open new Terminal window from Python, passing command to be executed

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I am using the following two lines of Python code to open a new Terminal window from a Python script, and this works fine:

```
import os
os.system('open -a Terminal .')
```

Now I would like to pass the new Terminal window a command to be executed, for example

```
ls
```

How can I do that?

Comment: See this thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308415/execute-terminal-command-from-python-in-new-terminal-window

Comment: You want to make Terminal open with the starting point of something like `bash -c "ls; exec bash"`. I'm not familiar with OS X, but in most Linux terminal emulators you can pass it in a flag.

Comment: Actually, none of the solutions for OS X explained in the recommended thread works...

Comment: I think [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989349/running-a-command-in-a-new-mac-os-x-terminal-window) is at least a partial duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
import appscript

appscript.app('Terminal').do_script('ls')  # or any other command you choose
```

Comment: appscript module hasn't been supported or updated in several years.

Comment: I could no longer download the appscript module.  The answer should no longer be accepted since it will waste peoples time.  Instead use the applescript module which is still alive and kicking.  :)

Comment: The usage of the applescript module is similar: applescript.tell.app( 'Terminal', 'do script "' + cmd + '"', background=True )

Comment: Still, don't downvote old answers because we can't future-proof anything.  Just create a new answer

Answer (score 3):

Since the old answer is depreciated,

Download applescript if you havent,

```
pip3 install applescript
```

python script

```
from applescript import tell

#set what command you want to run here
yourCommand = 'ls'

tell.app( 'Terminal', 'do script "' + yourCommand + '"')
```