# Running a command in MacOs terminal from java

Tags: java, macos

I'm trying to run a command line in a mac terminal using java code (particularly a ProcessBuilder).

I'm coding in a Windows environment and then exporting it to a Mac into a Jar Executable File.

I managed to open the terminal using the code posted below, but once there, the commands are not running, the terminal keeps dead, waiting for a keyboard input.

I will show a simple example for what I want to do:

```
String[] arguments = new String[] {"/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal", "-c", "pwd"};
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(arguments).start();
```

The code seems to run fine until it reaches the "-c" parameter, and then it does nothing else.

Does someone know how to solve this problem? Thanks!

EDIT: I've also tried without the "-c", but same result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a command in a new Mac OS X Terminal window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989349/running-a-command-in-a-new-mac-os-x-terminal-window)

Comment: The reason why this doesn't work from Java is that it doesn't work from anywhere. You should first find a command that *can* run a program in a new terminal, and only then try to invoke that from Java.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 try {
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command");
 } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: Ok, tried like this Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal -c pwd"), and also without the "-c" parameter. Same result, the bash seems not to be getting the command after it opens.