# Open New Terminal Window from Perl Script and Execute SSH command

Tags: macos, perl, ssh

I have a current perl script that I was executing on a windows machine in cygwin, that was opening a new cygwin terminal window and ssh'ing into a remote machine.

Trying to duplicate the mintty command on mac.

```
if ($noexec) {
    system("echo mintty -s 160,40 $cursor -o 
    BackgroundColour=$color -o 
    Title='\"$title\"' -e ssh $url \&");
} else {
    system("mintty -s 160,40 $cursor -o BackgroundColour=$color -o 
    Title=\"$title\" -e ssh $url \&");
}
```

Comment: "Duplicate" how? Do you have a command named `mintty` or are you trying to ask what to replace it with?

Comment: Sorry, trying to replace current mintty command that works on windows with cygwin with applicable mac terminal command.

Comment: The Mac Terminal is `/Applications/Terminal.app` but you probably don't need to open a separate window; just run your script in an existing Terminal window if that's what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a command in a new Mac OS X Terminal window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989349/running-a-command-in-a-new-mac-os-x-terminal-window)

Comment: The script is used to launch multiple sessions, so want a new window with each execution.

Comment: suggested page does not answer specific requirement stated here.

Comment: How so? Both `open Terminal command` and `osascript "tell Terminal..."` should fulfill your stated requirements.

Comment: @tripleee because I can't get these commands to execute inside the perl script

Comment: At least `perl -e 'system("open -a Terminal.all /tmp/testing")'` works for me when `/tmp/testing` is an executable shell script. Are you omitting something from the question or can you reproduce this? Do you need instructions for how to write a temporary shell script to a file?

Comment: @triplee I feel like all the information is provided here.  The script is a perl script so perl command is not needed.  See code snippet.  The perl script launches a new terminal window on windows and executes ssh command.  Trying to do that on Mac.  I don't want to call another script, but that may be what I have to do.  I just want to open -a Terminal.all and pass it ssh command and url variable not another file/script.

Comment: The explicit `perl` command is just to show you what exactly I did. If your script does something fundamentally different then that is information which should be explained in more detail in the question; if not, I have showed you exactly how to solve the problem in your script. The `osascript` solution doesn't require the commands to be in a separate script file so maybe go with that (and there may be a separate convenient Perl binding so you don't have to go through `os.system()`.

Comment: But so this still seems to me like you should accept the proposed duplicate, or explain in more detail how the answers there are unsuitable.

Comment: @tripleee this is not a duplicate because I am asking specifically how to replace the code above to open a new terminal and pass it an ssh command from a perl script on a mac.  The script code above works on a windows machine.  Any answer not addressing the specific question is not helpful to me.  I appreciate you trying to help, but showing what you did when it's different than what I am asking is not helpful.  I apologize if I am not being clear in my ask, but I feel like I spelled it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple translation of your code to use Applescript to perform the task, as explained in the proposed duplicate [Running a command in a new Mac OS X Terminal window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989349/running-a-command-in-a-new-mac-os-x-terminal-window)

```
if ($noexec) {
    system(qq{echo osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "ssh $url \& "'});
} else {
    system(qq{osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "ssh $url \& "'});
}
```

Running the `ssh` command in the background seems like a very odd thing to do. Probably you should replace `\&` with `; exit`.

I'm not sure what the `mintty` options mean (I guess set the geometry to 160x40 and pick a particular cursor?) so I haven't attempted to implement those. https://superuser.com/questions/1188772/mac-command-to-change-the-background-color-in-a-terminal shows how to set the background color in Terminal via Applescript, for example.

If `mintty` or Windows `ssh` really accepts a URL to connect to (something like `ssh://username@hostname` perhaps?) you will have to pick it apart and extract only the parameters which are acceptable to U*x `ssh` (like `username@hostname` without the `ssh://` protocol specifier).

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18727/problem-setting-terminal-window-bounds-with-applescript explores setting a Terminal window's dimensions from Applescript.

Comment: There may be Perl-native solutions which allow you to  bypass the `system()` call and provide better Applescript integration. https://metacpan.org/pod/Mac::OSA::Simple looks like a simple way to do that but I have no idea if it's current and supported.