# Starting zero alpha and ratel in a single command e.g. in MacOSX and other environments

Tags: dgraph

https://dgraph.io/tour/intro/2/

asks for three docker commands being run in different terminals:

- zero
- alpha
- ratel

I'd rather start things from a single script dgraph within Mac OSX 10.3.6 and other environments and use e.g. the terminal app to call the different scripts along the lines of [Running a command in a new Mac OS X Terminal window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989349/running-a-command-in-a-new-mac-os-x-terminal-window)

**How can the script below adapted for other environments like Unix and Windows?**

**dgraph**

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# WF 2020-08-05
# see https://dgraph.io/tour/intro/2/

version=v20.03.0

#ansi colors
#http://www.csc.uvic.ca/~sae/seng265/fall04/tips/s265s047-tips/bash-using-colors.html
blue='\033[0;34m'
red='\033[0;31m'
green='\033[0;32m' # '\e[1;32m' is too bright for white bg.
endColor='\033[0m'

#
# a colored message
#   params:
#     1: l_color - the color of the message
#     2: l_msg - the message to display
#
color_msg() {
  local l_color="$1"
  local l_msg="$2"
  echo -e "${l_color}$l_msg${endColor}"
}

#
# error
#
# show the given error message on stderr and exit
#
#   params:
#     1: l_msg - the error message to display
#
error() {
  local l_msg="$1"
  # use ansi red for error
  color_msg $red "Error:" 1>&2
  color_msg $red "\t$l_msg" 1>&2
  exit 1
}


# show usage
#
usage() {
  echo "$0 [-h|--help|-k|--kill"
  echo ""
  echo "-b | --bash: start a bash terminal shell within the currently running container"
  echo "-h | --help: show this usage"
  echo "-k | --kill: stop the docker image"
  exit 1
}

#
# stop the docker image
#
stopImage() {
  color_msg $blue "stopping and removing dgraph image ..."
  docker stop dgraph
  docker rm dgraph
  color_msg $green "...done"
}

#
# start a bash shell within the currently running container
#
bashInto() {
  sudo docker exec -it dgraph bash
}

#
# dgraph zero
#
zero() {
  docker run -it -p 5080:5080 -p 6080:6080 -p 8080:8080 \
  -p 9080:9080 -p 8000:8000 -v ~/dgraph:/dgraph --name dgraph \
  dgraph/dgraph:$version dgraph zero
}

#
# dgraph alpha
#
alpha() {
  docker exec -it dgraph dgraph alpha --lru_mb 2048 --zero localhost:5080 --whitelist 0.0.0.0/0
}

#
# dgraph ratel
#
ratel() {
  docker exec -it dgraph dgraph-ratel
}

me=$0
dir=$(dirname $0)
base=$(basename $0)
if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
case $base in
  dgraph)
    # Run Dgraph zero
    # And in another, run ratel (Dgraph UI)
    # In another terminal, now run Dgraph alpha
    for option in zero ratel alpha
    do
      #echo $dir $option
      open -a terminal.app $dir/$option
      # wait a bit
      sleep 2
    done
    ;;
    alpha) alpha;;
    ratel) ratel;;
    zero) zero;;
  esac
fi
# commandline option
while [  "$1" != ""  ]
do
  option="$1"
  case $option in
    alpha) alpha;;
    ratel) ratel;;
    zero) zero;;
    -b|--bash) bashInto;;
    -k|--kill) stopImage;;
    -h|--help) usage;;
  esac
  shift
done
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/DgraphAndWeaviateTest/blob/master/scripts/dgraph now has a script working on Linux (tested with travis/Ubuntu 18.04 LTS  - bionic).

See also https://travis-ci.org/github/WolfgangFahl/DgraphAndWeaviateTest/jobs/715131236

**usage**

```sh
scripts/dgraph -h
scripts/dgraph [-b|--bash|-h|--help|-k|--kill|-p|--pull]

-b | --bash: start a bash terminal shell within the currently running container
-h | --help: show this usage
-k | --kill: stop the docker image
-p | --pull: pull the docker image
```

**dgraph**

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# WF 2020-08-05
#
# Starts zero alpha and ratel docker based with one script
#
# see https://dgraph.io/tour/intro/2/
# see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63260073/starting-zero-alpha-and-ratel-in-a-single-command-e-g-in-macosx-and-other-envir
# see https://discuss.dgraph.io/t/dgraph-start-script/9231

version=v20.03.0
# interative tty option for docker
it="-it"

os=$(uname)
case $os in
  Linux)
    docker="docker"
    it="";;
    #docker="sudo docker";;
  Darwin)
    docker="docker";;
  *)
    docker="docker";;
esac

#ansi colors
#http://www.csc.uvic.ca/~sae/seng265/fall04/tips/s265s047-tips/bash-using-colors.html
blue='\033[0;34m'
red='\033[0;31m'
green='\033[0;32m' # '\e[1;32m' is too bright for white bg.
endColor='\033[0m'

#
# a colored message
#   params:
#     1: l_color - the color of the message
#     2: l_msg - the message to display
#
color_msg() {
  local l_color="$1"
  local l_msg="$2"
  echo -e "${l_color}$l_msg${endColor}"
}

#
# error
#
# show the given error message on stderr and exit
#
#   params:
#     1: l_msg - the error message to display
#
error() {
  local l_msg="$1"
  # use ansi red for error
  color_msg $red "Error:" 1>&2
  color_msg $red "\t$l_msg" 1>&2
  exit 1
}


# show usage
#
usage() {
  echo "$0 [-h|--help|-k|--kill"
  echo ""
  echo "-b | --bash: start a bash terminal shell within the currently running container"
  echo "-h | --help: show this usage"
  echo "-k | --kill: stop the docker image"
  echo "-p | --pull: pull the docker image"
  exit 1
}

#
# stop the docker image
#
stopImage() {
  color_msg $blue "stopping and removing dgraph image ..."
  $docker stop dgraph
  $docker rm dgraph
  color_msg $green "...done"
}

#
# pull the docker image
#
pullImage() {
  color_msg $blue "pulling dgraph image $version ..."
  $docker pull dgraph/dgraph:$version
  color_msg $green "...done"
}

#
# start a bash shell within the currently running container
#
bashInto() {
  $docker exec -it dgraph bash
}

#
# dgraph zero
#
zero() {
  # Let’s create a folder for storing Dgraph data outside of the container:
  mkdir -p ~/dgraph
  $docker run $it -p 5080:5080 -p 6080:6080 -p 8080:8080 \
  -p 9080:9080 -p 8000:8000 -v ~/dgraph:/dgraph --name dgraph \
  dgraph/dgraph:$version dgraph zero
}

#
# dgraph alpha
#
alpha() {
  $docker exec $it dgraph dgraph alpha --lru_mb 2048 --zero localhost:5080 --whitelist 0.0.0.0/0
}

#
# dgraph ratel
#
ratel() {
  $docker exec $it dgraph dgraph-ratel
}

me=$0
dir=$(dirname $0)
base=$(basename $0)
if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
case $base in
  dgraph)
    # Run Dgraph zero
    # And in another, run ratel (Dgraph UI)
    # In another terminal, now run Dgraph alpha
    for option in zero ratel alpha
    do
      # make sure linked versions of command are available
      if [ ! -f $dir/$option ]
      then
        color_msg $blue "creating link $dir/$option"
        ln $dir/dgraph $dir/$option
      fi
      #echo $dir $option
      color_msg $blue "starting dgraph $option ..."
      case $os in
          Darwin)
            open -a terminal.app $dir/$option
          ;;
          # https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the
          Linux)
            #for terminal in gnome-terminal xterm konsole
            #do
            #    which $terminal > /dev/null
            #  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
            #    then
            #    $terminal -e $dir/$option
            #    break
            #  fi
            #done
            nohup $dir/$option > /tmp/$option.log 2>&1 &
            sleep 2
            tail /tmp/$option.log
          ;;
          *)
            error "unsupported operating system $os"
      esac
      # wait a bit
      sleep 2
    done
    ;;
    alpha) alpha;;
    ratel) ratel;;
    zero) zero;;
  esac
fi
# commandline option
while [  "$1" != ""  ]
do
  option="$1"
  case $option in
    alpha) alpha;;
    ratel) ratel;;
    zero) zero;;
    -p|--pull) pullImage;;
    -b|--bash) bashInto;;
    -k|--kill) stopImage;;
    -h|--help) usage;;
  esac
  shift
done
```